# In a triangle $ABC$, $\angle B = 2\angle C$, the ray $AD$ is the angle bisector of $\angle A$ and $DC = AB$. Then what is the measure of $\angle A$?

Tags: geometry

This is the 25th question from https://mprakashinstitute.com/11thStd/11thEntranceTest_30April2023.pdf

My instincts are telling me to use the angle bisector theorem, but after using it I get stuck after doing the following step:
$$
BD\cdot AC = AB\cdot DC = AB^2 = DC^2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $BT$ be the angle bisector of $\angle B$ .

Let $\angle C=x^{\circ} \;\&\; \angle CBT=x^{\circ} \therefore\; BT=TC \because \Delta BCT$ is an isoceles triangle.

$\angle ABT=\angle C=x^{\circ}$ .

$AB=DC$ is given

So $ABT \;\&\; TCD$ become congruent.

Hence $AT=TD \implies \angle ADT=\angle CAD=\angle A/2$ ,

Also by congruence : $\angle TDC=\angle A$ .

So $\angle ADC=3 \angle A/2 \;,\; \angle DAC=\angle A/2 \;,\; \angle TCD=x^{\circ}$ .

$\because \angle ACD + \angle CDA + \angle DAC =180$ we get :

$2(180-3x)+x=180 \implies 180=5x \implies x = 36$

Answer (score 1):

Lucid' method is purely geometrical and very elegant, but if you need an algebraic approach, I am posting my answer for your reference :

If you know the sine rule of triangle (it states that $\frac{a}{\sin A} = \frac{b}{\sin B} = \frac{c}{\sin C} = 2R$ (where R is the radius of cirumcircle of $\Delta ABC$)

Let $\angle C = x \implies \angle B = 2x \implies \angle A = \pi - 3x \implies \angle DAC = \angle DAB = \frac{\pi - 3x}{2}$

As sum of angles in a triangle is $\pi^c$, we used this above to get $\angle A = \pi - 3x$ and now using it in $\Delta ADC \;\&\; \Delta ADB$ to get $\angle ADC = \pi - x - \frac{\pi - 3x}{2} = \frac{\pi + x}{2} \;\&\; \angle ADB = \pi - 2x - \frac{\pi - 3x}{2} = \frac{\pi - x}{2}$

Using sin rule in $\Delta ACD$ we get :

$\frac{AD}{\sin x} = \frac{CD}{\sin (\frac{\pi - 3x}{2})}$

Dividing by $2 \cos x$ on both sides and using $\sin (2x) = 2\sin x \cos x \;,\; 2\sin A \cos B = \sin (A+B) + \sin (A-B) (A = \frac{\pi - 3x}{2} \;\&\; B = x)$ we get :

$\frac{AD}{\sin 2x} = \frac{CD}{\sin (\frac{\pi - x}{2}) + \sin (\frac{\pi - 5x}{2})}$

Using sin rule in $\Delta ABD$ we get :

$\frac{AB}{\sin (\frac{\pi - x}{2})} = \frac{AD}{\sin 2x}$

Equating $\frac{AD}{\sin 2x}$ we get :

$\frac{CD}{\sin (\frac{\pi - x}{2}) + \sin (\frac{\pi - 5x}{2})} = \frac{AB}{\sin (\frac{\pi - x}{2})}$

Given that AB = CD, we get :

$\sin (\frac{\pi - x}{2}) + \sin (\frac{\pi - 5x}{2}) = \sin (\frac{\pi - x}{2})$

$\therefore \sin (\frac{\pi - 5x}{2}) = 0 \implies \frac{\pi - 5x}{2} = 0$ or $\frac{\pi - 5x}{2} = \pi$ (not possible as then x comes out to be negative)

$\therefore \pi - 5x = 0 \implies x = \pi / 5 = 36^{\circ}$

Comment: If we talk about trig based approaches I believe this can also be done by the relationship $a^2=b(b+c)$ between side lengths when one angle is double another

Comment: I am unfortunately not aware about that so I could not use that, maybe that's some geometrical result that I am not aware of

Comment: It's actually not a theorom to remember proving that was actually came as a very old math olympiad problem, but u can use it as a lemma here

Comment: That is true, but I could not assume the OP would know this previous math Olympiad problem when it is not even a theorem or I would have to prove it, and that would rather employ more steps

Comment: indeed , ......

Answer (score 0):

The moment you represent the problem on paper with angle(B) = 2C and angle(C) = C,

Now drop an angular bisector from B onto AC and that would give you angle(DBC) = C and angle(DBA) = C;

If you look at the triangle DBC, you would figure out to be an isosceles triangle as we see that angle(DBC) = angle(BCD) = C

This would further imply that DB=DC (Sides opposite to equal angles are equal)

Now we have DB = DC = AB (as mentioned in the question)

And if we now look at triangle ABD, we see to figure that out as an isosceles triangle with DB = AB so which would imply that angle(BDA) = angle(BAD) (angles opposite to equal sides)

In triangle ABD, angle(ABD) = C as we have it at the beginning
angle(ABD) + 2*angle(BAD) = 180 degrees
This would give us angle(BAD) = 90 - C/2

In triangle ABC, angle(BAC) + angle(ABC) + angle(ACB) = 180 degrees

We know that angle(BAC) = angle(BAD) = 90-C/2

90-C/2 + 2*C + C = 180 degrees

Upon solving, we get C = 36 degrees

angle(A) = 90-C/2 which is 72 degrees

Hope this helped :)